# Automatically go to furthest right (last horizontal child) then back to furthest left(first child) in a horizontal scroll view

Tags: java, android, xml

I have **cards** in a horizontal LinearLayout which is then in a `HorizontalScrollView` that I would like to rotate about left to right and back like an image slideshow.

Here is my XML, it contains **5 cards** which are in horizontal alignment

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/horizontal_scroller"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:scrollbars="none">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="180dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"

            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingBottom="8dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/testimage" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:gravity="end"
                    android:text="USD 300"
                    android:textAlignment="viewEnd"
                    android:textColor="#ce375e"
                    android:textSize="15dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="9dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:text="Product 1"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="180dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"

            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingBottom="8dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/testimage" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:gravity="end"
                    android:text="USD 300"
                    android:textAlignment="viewEnd"
                    android:textColor="#ce375e"
                    android:textSize="15dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="9dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:text="Product 2"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="180dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"

            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingBottom="8dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/testimage" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:gravity="end"
                    android:text="USD 300"
                    android:textAlignment="viewEnd"
                    android:textColor="#ce375e"
                    android:textSize="15dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="9dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:text="Product 3"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="180dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"

            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingBottom="8dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/testimage" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:gravity="end"
                    android:text="USD 300"
                    android:textAlignment="viewEnd"
                    android:textColor="#ce375e"
                    android:textSize="15dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="9dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:text="Product 4"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="180dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"

            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingBottom="8dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/testimage" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:gravity="end"
                    android:text="USD 300"
                    android:textAlignment="viewEnd"
                    android:textColor="#ce375e"
                    android:textSize="15dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="9dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:text="Product 5"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

I have tried using tags such as `<ViewFlipper` with that users cannot scroll themselves within the layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a timer for continuous scrolling, and using `canScrollHorizontally()` to check wether it reached the furthest right then start scrolling left,
`canScrollHorizontally()` takes positive int for right direction, negative int for left direction

```
private HorizontalScrollView scrollView;
private boolean scrollingLeft;
int pace = 50;
private Timer timer;

    timer = new Timer("horizontalScrollViewTimer");
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (scrollView.canScrollHorizontally(1)&&!scrollingLeft ) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Scrolling right");
                        scrollView.smoothScrollBy(pace, 0);
                    }
                    else {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Scrolling left");
                        scrollingLeft =true;
                        scrollView.smoothScrollBy(-pace, 0);
                        if(!scrollView.canScrollHorizontally(-1)) // reached the furthest left turn of scrolling left
                            scrollingLeft = false;
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }, 3000, 50);
```